# Regarding low storage after updating the O.S

Tags: system-apps

In my phone I have a total of 8 GB space but system uses a block of 3.37 GB.

So how can I remove old update after completion of new update?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to remove old update.
It gets removed by itself during the process.
Transfer apps to SD card or uninstall some.

Answer (score 1):

The 3GB (approx.) of usage on all Windows Phones is actually the operating system, and therefore cannot be removed.

OS update do require additional free space, but once the update process is complete, those temporary files are removed.

Depending on what Windows Phone you have, you can add an SD card for additional space. Space on the SD card can also be used to install OS updates if the Phone memory is nearly full.

If your phone is up to date, use [Storage Sense](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/storage-on-my-phone) to understand how the space is being used (Apps, Music, Photos, etc) and delete what you don't want.